# Unable to install git in pydroid . Help please

Tags: git, installation, pydroid

Unable to install git in pydroid

/storage/emulated/0 $ pip install git

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement git (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for git

Please help

Comment: What leads you to believe that `pip install git` is a way to install Git? (Is this an instruction on some web page, for instance?)

Comment: I am installing git to use in buildozer to make Android app in my smartphone. Git is necessary to do that. I am using pydroid app in my smartphone. Please help how to install git.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Git is required for that, but to install Git on Linux, you simply use the installer that comes with your Linux system (not `pip install`, which is for Python packages). To install Git on Windows, you'd generally pick up one of the Git-for-Windows distributions.

Comment: I installed git using termux app in my smartphone but when using buildozer it says ' it didn't find git , please install'. Please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with buildozer, but https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ does not mention Git. If you do need to install Git, see instructions for your OS, whatever that is.